# Applicationinsights customized telemetry leads to ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get the UserName of connected users for our application insights services but adding the custom telemetry to log UserName gives me a `System.ObjectDisposedException occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code` error.

Exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Safe handle has been closed
```

StackTrace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Safe handle has been closed
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
   at Webeco.Infrastructure.Logging.AppInsightsInitializer.Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry) in C:\Users\SESEGU\Documents\Projects\WebEco\WebEco.Infrastructure\Logging\AppInsightsInitializer.cs:line 22
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient.Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
        private readonly ILogger<TelemetryInitializer> _logger;

        public TelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, ILogger<TelemetryInitializer> logger)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
            if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
            if (!requestTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("UserName"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    requestTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("UserName", "NA");
                }
                else
                {
                    requestTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("UserName", _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone ran into similar problems and how did you fix it?

Comment: just want to confirm, it's a asp.net project? not .net core?

Comment: You didn't post the exception text, call stack or indicated where the error occured, so people can only guess. Each request has its own HttpContext instance that gets destroyed when the request ends.

Comment: @IvanYang It's targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: Post the *full* exception text, including the stack trace. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. I suspect the problem is trying to call `HttpContext` after it was disposed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added the full stacktrace above.